# Joining Array In Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Hi I want to join multiple arrays in python, using numpy to form multidimensional arrays, it's inside of a for loop, this is a pseudocode

```
import numpy as np
h = np.zeros(4)
for x in range(3):
   x1 = some array of length of 4 returned from a previous function (3,5,6,7)
   h = np.concatenate((h,x1), axis =0)
```

The first iteration goes fine, but during the second iteration on the for loop I get the following error,

> ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions

The output array should look something like this

```
 [[0,0,0,0],[3,5,6,7],[6,3,6,7]]
```

etc

So how can I join the arrays?

Thanks

Comment: Does it have to be with numpy? You can simply do `list1.append(list2)`

Comment: I tried but it gives the following error AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: I was referring to Python lists, not numpy arrays.

Comment: Did you check the `shape` of `h` after the first concatenate?  Don't use `concatenate` unless you understand the dimensions of your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [vstack](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html). It allows you to stack arrays. You take a sequence of arrays and stack them vertically to make a single array

```
 import numpy as np  
 h = np.zeros(4)
 for x in range(3):
     x1 = [3,5,6,7]
     h = np.vstack((h,x1))
     # not h = np.concatenate((h,x1), axis =0)

  print h
```

Output:

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 3.  5.  6.  7.]
 [ 3.  5.  6.  7.]
 [ 3.  5.  6.  7.]]
```

more edits later.
If you do want to use cocatenate only, you can do the following way as well:

```
 import numpy as np
 h1 = np.zeros(4)

 for x in range(3):
      x1 = np.array([3,5,6,7])
      h1= np.concatenate([h1,x1.T], axis =0)

 print h1.shape
 print h1.reshape(4,4)
```

Output:

```
(16,)
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 3.  5.  6.  7.]
 [ 3.  5.  6.  7.]
 [ 3.  5.  6.  7.]]
```

Both have different applications. You can choose according to your need.

Answer (score 1):

It is best to collect values in a list, and perform the concatenate or array creation once, at the end.

```
h = [np.zeros(4)]
for x in range(3):
   x1 = some array of length of 4 returned from a previous function (3,5,6,7)
   h = h.append(x1)
h = np.array(h)
# or h = np.vstack(h)
```

All the `concatenate/stack/array` functions takes a list of multiple items.  It is faster to append to a list than to do a concatenate of 2 items.

======================

Let's try your approach step by step:

```
In [189]: h=np.zeros(4)
In [190]: h
Out[190]: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])    # 1d array (4,) shape
In [191]: x1=np.array([3,5,6,7])     # another 1d
In [192]: h1=np.concatenate((h,x1),axis=0)
In [193]: h1
Out[193]: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  3.,  5.,  6.,  7.])
In [194]: h1.shape
Out[194]: (8,)       # also a 1d array, but with 8 items
In [195]: x1=np.array([6,3,6,7])
In [196]: h1=np.concatenate((h1,x1),axis=0)
In [197]: h1
Out[197]: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  3.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  6.,  3.,  6.,  7.])
```

In this case I'm adding (4,) arrays one after the other, still getting a 1d array.

If I go back an create `x1` as 2d `(1,4)`:

```
In [198]: h=np.zeros(4)
In [199]: x1=np.array([[6,3,6,7]])
In [200]: h1=np.concatenate((h,x1),axis=0)
...
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

I get this dimension error right away.

The fact that you get the error on the 2nd iteration suggests that the 1st `x1` is `(4,)`, but the 2nd is 2d.

When you have dimensions errors like this, check the shapes.

`vstack` adds dimensions to the inputs, as needed, so you can build 2d arrays:

```
In [207]: h=np.zeros(4)
In [208]: x1=np.array([3,5,6,7])
In [209]: h=np.vstack((h,x1))
In [210]: h
Out[210]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 3.,  5.,  6.,  7.]])
In [211]: x1=np.array([6,3,6,7])
In [212]: h=np.vstack((h,x1))
In [213]: h
Out[213]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 3.,  5.,  6.,  7.],
       [ 6.,  3.,  6.,  7.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of doing this.  I'll list a few examples:

First, we import `numpy` and define a function that generates those arrays of length 4.

```python
import numpy as np

def previous_function_returning_array_of_length_4(x):
    return np.array(range(4)) + x
```

The first way involves creating a list of arrays, then calling `numpy.array()` to convert the list to a 2D array.

```python
h0 = np.zeros(4)
arrays = [h0]
for x in range(3):
    x1 = previous_function_returning_array_of_length_4(x)
    arrays.append(x1)

h = np.array(arrays)
```

You can do the same with `np.vstack()`:

```python
h0 = np.zeros(4)
arrays = [h0]
for x in range(3):
    x1 = previous_function_returning_array_of_length_4(x)
    arrays.append(x1)

h = np.vstack(arrays)
```

Alternatively, if you know how many arrays you are going to create, you can create the 2D array first and fill in the values:

```python
h = np.zeros((4, 4))
for ii in range(3):
    x1 = previous_function_returning_array_of_length_4(ii)
    h[ii + 1, ...] = x1
```

There are more ways, but hopefully, this will give you an idea of what to do.